# What does s-/-- and s-/\Z-- in perl mean?

Tags: regex, perl

I am a beginner in perl and I have a query regarding pattern matching.
I came across a line in perl where it was written

```
  $variable =~ s-/\Z--;
```

And as the code goes ahead some another variable was assigned

```
  $variable1 =~ s-/--;
```

Can you please tell me what does these 2 lines do?
 I want to know what does `s-/\Z--` and `s-/--` mean.

Comment: Several of the answers below show a mo-bettah (maybe) version of `s-/\Z--`. The standard delimiter is a forward slash. Here is a version of the same substitution but using the standard slash delimiter: `s/\/\Z//` . The advantage of this is that other readers will more readily see this as a substitution. The disadvantage is that that ugly mass of slashes and backslashes makes it look like a drunken chicken took a walk over the code. Remember the perl motto: There's always more than one way to do it. In this case, there are a lot of other options than the forward slash as a separator.

Answer (score 7):

```
$variable =~ s-/\Z--;
```

`-` is used as a delimiter here. However, best practice suggests that you either use `/` or `{}` as delimiters.

It could be re-written as:

```
$variable =~ s{/\Z}{};  # remove a / at the end of a string
```

Consider:

```
$variable1 =~ s-/--;
```

Again, it could be re-written as:

```
$variable1 =~ s{/}{};  # remove the first /
```

Answer (score 6):

The `s///` operator in Perl is a *substitution* operation, which performs a search-and-replace on a string using a special kind of pattern called a *regular expression*. You can read more about regular expressions and Perl's pattern matching in the man pages that come with Perl:

- [`man perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)
- [`man perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

If you don't have these on your system, try searching Google for the same.

Applying a substitution to a variable is done with the `=~` operator. So the following replaces all instances of 'foo' in the variable `$var` with 'bar'.

```
$var =~ s/foo/bar/;
```

All the Perl operators are documented on the 'perlop' man page.

Even though the most common separator character is a slash (hence s///), you can also use any other punctuation character as a separator. So in this case, the author has decided to use the dash (`-`) as the separator.

Here's the same line of code above using dash as a separator:

```
$var =~ s-foo-bar-;
```

In your case, the dash doesn't seem to add any clarity to the code, so it might be best to update it to use the conventional slashes instead.

Comment: "you can also use any other punctuation character as a separator" - actually you can use pretty much ANY character as the delimiter :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `s///` search and replace function in perl can be used with different delimeters, which is what is done in this case. They have replaced `/` with the minus sign `-`, or dash.

The `s-/--` removes the first `/` from the string. 
The `s-/\Z--` matches and removes a slash at the end of the line. I think this is better written: `s{/$}{}`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$variable1 =~ s-/--;`could be written as

   ```
   $variable =~ s{/}{}xms;
   ```

   or this

   ```
   $variable =~ s/ \/ //xms;
   ```

   It means delete the first `/` in the string.
2. Regarding `s-/\Z--`, it is usually written like this

   ```
   $variable =~ s{/ \Z}{}xms;
   ```

   or this

   ```
   $variable =~ s/ \/ \Z //xms;
   ```

   It means delete a `/` if it is at the end of the string (`\Z`).